# Convert Flat List to Nested List (3 levels deep)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I'm a newbie in Python, I am trying to convert my flat list data to nested list data, found a solution here in stackoverflow but didn't achieve my goal..

```
def build_multilevel(entries):
    result = []
    stack = [result]
    for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
        if entry == '{':
            # convert last element of the top-most list on the stack
            # to a new, nested list, and push that new list on top
            stack[-1][-1] = [stack[-1][-1]]
            stack.append(stack[-1][-1])
        elif entry == '}':
            stack.pop()
        else:
            stack[-1].append(entry)
    print("File content data type is: ", type(stack))
    print(len(stack))
    print(stack)
    return stack
```

My goal is to have  this kind of data:

FROM THIS:

```
['2019-10-09T06:57:01.605Z', 'START', 'RequestId:', 'ABC123', 'Version:', 'LATEST', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.685Z', 'ABC123', 'INFO', 'event.name=UAT', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', 'ABC123', 'INFO', '{', '"messageVersion":', '"1.0",','"invocationSource":', '"Success",','"userId":', '"User",','"requestAttributes":','{', '"type":', '"Text",', '"user-id":', '"ABC123",', '"name":', '"UATCares",','"type":', '"Media"', '},', '"machine":', '{', '"name":', '"UAT",', '"alias":', '"UAT",', '"version":', '"5"', '},','"Mode":', '"Text",',  '"Intent":', '{', '"name":', '"Services",','"slots":', '{},','"slotDetails":', '{},','"confirmationStatus":', '"None"', '},', '"inputTranscript":', '"Pay', 'Serve"', '}']
```

TO THIS:

```
['2019-10-09T06:57:01.605Z', 'START', 'RequestId:', 'ABC123', 'Version:', 'LATEST', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.685Z', 'ABC123', 'INFO', 'event.name=UAT', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', '2019-10-09T06:57:01.686Z', 'ABC123', 'INFO', '{', 
    '"messageVersion":', '"1.0",',
    '"invocationSource":', '"Success",',
    '"userId":', '"User",',
    '"requestAttributes":',
        '{', 
            '"type":', '"Text",', 
            '"user-id":', '"ABC123",', 
            '"name":', '"UATCares",',
            '"type":', '"Media"', 
        '},', 
    '"machine":', 
        '{', 
            '"name":', '"UAT",', 
            '"alias":', '"UAT",', 
            '"version":', '"5"', 
        '},', 
    '"Mode":', '"Text",', 
    '"Intent":', 
        '{', 
            '"name":', '"Services",',
            '"slots":', '{},',
            '"slotDetails":', '{},',
            '"confirmationStatus":', '"None"', 
        '},', 
    '"inputTranscript":', '"Pay', 'Serve"', 
    '}'
]
```

Comment: It looks like you need a dictionary instead of a list in this case; where is your data coming from? are you reading a file? if yes it's worth reading this with `json.load()`. see more information [here](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)

Comment: Where would you get the first list (which looks like tokenized JSON) in the first place?

Comment: I got the data from s3 bucket, its an app log file. So meaning to say, I need to convert it to dictionary instead of list? Can you explain why? Thank you.

Comment: The items in the list are separated by commas by the way